# Math operators in child class of fractions.Fraction return parent class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Is it normal for an operator of the derived class to return objects of the base class? It happens when inheriting from `fractions.Fraction`:

```
class OtherFraction(Fraction):
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'OtherFraction({self.numerator}, {self.denominator})'

a = OtherFraction(1, 2)
b = OtherFraction(1, 3)
c = a + b
print(repr(a), repr(b), repr(c))
```

This prints: `OtherFraction(1, 2) OtherFraction(1, 3) Fraction(5, 6)`

I had expected math operations between `OtherFraction`'s to return `OtherFraction`'s, but it returns a `Fraction` instead.

It seems that I can force it to return `OtherFraction` by overriding each operation, but that sounds like a lot of redundant work.

```
class OtherFraction(Fraction):
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'OtherFraction({self.numerator}, {self.denominator})'

    def __add__(self, other):
        return OtherFraction(super().__add__(other))

a = OtherFraction(1, 2)
b = OtherFraction(1, 3)
c = a + b
print(repr(a), repr(b), repr(c)
```

It now prints: `OtherFraction(1, 2) OtherFraction(1, 3) OtherFraction(5, 6)`

Is there any way of to make it work as expected without manually overriding all operators?
Or is it unreasonable of me to expect the behavior I describe? Perhaps I am violating important principles of object-oriented programming by expecting operators to return objects of the derived class.

Comment: It can be done with your own base classes, but base classes have to be designed in advance to expect this sort of usage. That said, it isn't clear what *practical problem you hope to solve* by creating the derived class in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The base class normally doesn't know the derived class exists, so cannot return instances of the derived class. I believe the Fraction class' is immutable so it returns a new Fraction object rather than modifying the existing object for add, etc., so you get the behaviour you see.

That basically means that you would have to override all the maths methods to get the behaviour you want.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve though, it may be that inheritance is not be the best choice.